# Getting wrong Form Data name when posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, form-data

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to a javascript function. When reviewing the post data I get incorrect data names.

HTML:

```
//Test function with button (HTML)
<button onClick='printList("projects",{"qid":1,"oid":3),getSampleEntity);'>Test getSampleEntity</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var getSampleEntity = function(oid, qid) {
    //Returns Object
    return $.ajax({ 
        url: URL + 'downloadQuadrat_Organism.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'organismID': oid, 'quadratID': qid },
        dataType: dataType
    });
}

....

var printList = function(lid,options,get) {
    var items = get(options);
    var list = $("ul#"+lid);

    list.empty();

    items.success(function(data){
        $.each(data, function(item,details) {
        var ul = $('<ul/>');
        ul.attr('id', lid+'_'+details.ID);
        var li = $('<li/>')
        .text(details.ID)
        .appendTo(list);
        ul.appendTo(list);

        $.each(details,function(key,value) {
                var li = $('<li/>')
                .text(key+': '+value)
                .appendTo(ul);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The resulting post data:

```
organismID[qid]:1
organismID[oid]:3
```

I see what is happening, but my question is how do I pass multiple parameters in to my printList() so that those parameters will be passed effectively to getSapleEntity()?

Comment: Your syntax is invalid, you should be getting an error in the console.  `{"qid":1,"oid":3)` should be `{"qid":1,"oid":3}` (the close parenthesis should be a close curly brace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var items = get(options.oid, options.qid);
```